# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: error while trying to do a subscription

Tags: go, graphql, apollo-client, gqlgen

i'm using Apollo graphgql Client for front-end and gqlgen for my bff service
here's my Apollo configuration code:

```
const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(createClient({
url: 'ws://localhost:8080/'}))
```

and here is how i created my graphql server:

```
srv := handler.NewDefaultServer(generated.NewExecutableSchema(generated.Config{Resolvers: &resolvers.Resolver{}})) 
srv.AddTransport(&transport.Websocket{})

srv.AddTransport(transport.POST{})

if helpers.Env("MODE") == "PRODUCTION" {
    cache, err := apq.NewCache(24 * time.Hour)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cannot create APQ redis cache: %v", err)
    }

    srv.Use(extension.AutomaticPersistedQuery{Cache: cache})
}



router.Handle("/", srv)

if helpers.Env("MODE") == "DEVELOPMENT" {
    router.Handle("/playground", playground.Handler("GraphQL playground", "/"))
    log.Printf("connect to http://localhost:%s/playground for GraphQL playground", port)
}

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router))
```

any idea how to fix this error?

i tried replacing  `'ws://localhost:8080/'` with `ws://localhost:8080/subscriptions` and `ws://localhost:8080/graphql` and `ws://myIP:8080/` but non of them worked